# Find $f$ such as its eigenvector associated to a given eigenvalue $-2$ is $v=(-1,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be an endomorphism such as

$f(1,0,1)=(1,2,1)$

$f(1,1,0)=(2,0,0)$

and $v=(-1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector respect to the eigenvalue $-2$

$1)$ Describe the $Im(f)$ and $Ker(f)$

$2)$ Describe explicitly $f$

$3)$ Determine if $f$ is diagonalizable

I've been give this exercise and I'm wondering if it lacks information in order to be solved or if it's me who lacks of information. Since I don't have a basis of the transformation defined and I can't either arbitrarily finish to define the function $f$ because must be a function that satisfies that the condition that $v=(-1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector. For the other side, I know that since $-2$ is eigenvalue satisfies that $(A+2Id)v=0$ but I don't know how to deduce the matrix of the transformation with this data! What am I missing here?

I'll be thankful if someone helps me!

Comment: As $f$ is basically a 3-by-3 matrix, explicitly write down and substitute the matrix entries based on the condition given should keep you going.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "substitute the matrix entries based on the given condition"?

Comment: Just assume $A$ is a 3-by-3 matrix satisfies $A(1,0,1)^T = (1,2,1)^T$ and so on. Then solve the matrix entries explicitly. Well this is only an approach, the answer has another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that$$f(1,0,1)=(1,2,1)\text{, that }f(1,1,0)=(2,0,0)\text{, and that }f(-1,1,1)=(2,-2,-2).$$Since $\{(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(-1,1,1)\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$, you know all that you need to know in order to work with $f$. For instance, since$$(1,0,0)=\frac13(1,0,1)+\frac13(1,1,0)-\frac13(-1,1,1),$$you know that$$f(1,0,0)=\frac13(1,2,1)+\frac13(2,0,0)-\frac13(2,-2,-2)=\left(\frac13,\frac43,1\right),$$an so on.

Comment: I'm sorry but how did you deduced that (-1,1,1) goes to (-2,2,2)?

Comment: I made a mistake; it's $(2,-2,-2)$. And I know that because you told that $v=(−1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector respect to the eigenvalue $−2$.

Comment: This is because (-1, 1, 1) is an eigenvector of f, that is $f(-1, 1, 1) = \lambda (-1, 1, 1)$ in our case, we are told $\lambda = -2$